# Change DNS for Thomson TG585 Cytanet Router

Tags: configuration, dns, router

I have a Cytanet Router (from Cyprus) and I need to change the DNS so I can watch my netflix, and other geographically blocked content. Any ideas?
To log in to the router I successfully got in by going to 192.168.10.25 and put in my username and password. (user=cytauser and password=blank) This is how they distribute their routers. 
Problem is, there is not GUI or browser console section to change DNS :-/.
Any help? I'm on a Windows 7 computer.

Answer (score 3):

So after searching for answers here is what I eventually found...
http://community.plus.net/library/dns/how-to-change-the-default-dns-servers-in-a-thomson-speedtouch-router/

However, here is the one specific to Cytanet (Cyprus) Thomson TG585 v7 on a Windows 7 machine with Telnet Client installed (See the link above to get telnet installed).

1. Go to Start and open windows command prompt.
2. type the following depending on your router IP address (mine was 192.168.10.254)

   telnet 192.168.10.254
3. Then you should get a screen asking you for a "Username:". In my case since it was for Cytanet ISP, I used 'cytauser' and blank password and worked. The factory default is 'Administrator' and empty password.

   Username: cytauser
   Password:
4. You should then see a window with a bunch of DOS design if you successfully signed in

   **__**  Thomson TG585 v7
                            **_/*_***/\
                           /         /\  7.4.3.2
                     /_       /  \
                   _/       /_____/**_ \  Copyright (c) 1999-2007, THOMSON
                  //       /  \       /\ \
          _____**//***_***/    \     / _/______
         /      / \       \    /    / /        /\
      **/      /   \       \  /    / /        / *_*
     / /      /     _____**/    / /        / /   /\
    /*/**_***/**_______________**/ /**____**/ /**_/  \
    \ \      \    _________**    \ \        \ \   \  /
     _\      \  /          /\    \ \        \ ___/
        \      /          /  \    \ \        \  /
         _____/          /    \    \ ________/
              /**______**/      \    \  /
              \     \      //
               \ /    /\  \    /***/
                /_***/  \  \  /
                \    \  /*_*/
5. Then type the following to see your current DNS settings.

   dns server route list
6. you should see a list of at least 2 entries with IP addresses, source, Label, Metric, Inf, etc.
7. Now you want to flush your dns servers which will delete the default ones. Type the following

   dns server flush
8. Now type the following to see if it actually flushed them, you should now see no entries for your DNS.

   dns server route list
9. Now you're ready to put in your DNS IP addresses that you got from UnBlock US or Unlocator. Type the following for each of the DNS entries. Notice xx.xx.xx.xx is for the numbers you were provided, don't actually put in xx.

   dns server route add dns=xxx.xx.xx.xxx metric=0 intf=pppInternet
10. Now do the same for the second IP/DNS address one you were provided.
11. Then go to the DNS Server List again and make sure it changed. You should see the numbers that you just added by using this command again.

    dns server route list
12. Once you confirmed the new entries have been added, you should save the settings by typing:

    saveall
13. You should be all set! Try resetting your Wifi or internet connection from your device and you should be good to go. Don't reboot/reset the router though.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I had to set intf=Internet, without ppp. The intf argument needs to match whatever you see in your initial route list.